# show route map between two address points

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I am working for door delivery app, here I am trying to show route map between pickup and dropping points. I've tried with the below code but showing straight line instead of a path.

```
     CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateArray[2];
     coordinateArray[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(17.4368, 78.4439);
     coordinateArray[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(16.5083, 80.6417);


     self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:2];
     [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:[self.routeLine boundingMapRect]]; //If you want the route to be visible

     [self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];

-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
  if(overlay == self.routeLine)
  {
    if(nil == self.routeLineView)
    {
      self.routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine];
      self.routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
      self.routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor];
      self.routeLineView.lineWidth = 5;

    }

    return self.routeLineView;
  }

  return nil;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can take reference from here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/30001/overlay-images-and-overlay-views-with-mapkit-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You must use MKRoute and MKDirections for routing on roads.

Check out this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKRoute_class/).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the *MKDirectionRequest* for routing direction.
Check out [this](http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/draw-route-between-2-points-on-map-with-ios7-mapkit-api/) link.